# RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: host_url failed to respond

Tags: java, network-programming, jax-ws, resteasy

Sometimes (happens randomly, sometimes after one Requests and sometimes after 10) my Batch-Job crashes with the following Exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: host_url failed to respond
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:327)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:227)
```

The exception is triggered from the following code:

```
public YpspResponse sendRequest(YpspRequest request) {
        return webTarget
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .post(Entity.xml(request))
                .readEntity(YpspResponse.class);
    }
```

WebTarget is initialized with this code:

```
            ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                    .socketTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectionPoolSize(500)
                    .keyStore(keyStore, ynetKeystorePassword.toCharArray())
                    .trustStore(trustStore);

            if (proxyConfiguration.useProxy()){
                logger.info("{}", proxyConfiguration.getHost());
                builder.defaultProxy(proxyConfiguration.getHost(), proxyConfiguration.getPort());
            }

            return builder
                    .build()
                    .target(ynetUrl)
                    .register(messageBodyReader)
                    .register(loggingFilter)
                    .register((ClientRequestFilter) requestContext -> {
                        byte[] auth = (username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
                        requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "BASIC " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth));
                        requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle("version", "1.1");
                    });
```

I am using RESTEASY: 3.12.1.FINAL

It appears that the `ResteasyClient` tries to use an already used connection instead of a new one. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What container are you running in? It's possible there was a bug fix for this. Maybe related to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-1715.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yeah this could be my error. I am using an adoptopenjdk:8-hotspot dockerimage. How can i fix my problem :)?

Comment: What container are you running in? If a non-Jakarta EE container can you try a newer version like 3.15.2.Final?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am using a Wildfly 20.0.1-FINAL. If I want to update Resteasy to Version 4.x.x I have to use a Wildfly 25.0.1-FINAL, but I can't migrate it that easy. Is there is different way to update Resteasy?

Comment: Upgrading to 4.x would be a bit trickier. You can upgrade to 3.15.2.Final though https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.15.2.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#upgrading-wildfly.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I am getting the same behaviour with resteasy-client:6.2.4, also it appears only when the application is deployed to docker. Are there any workarounds I can apply?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I've found the issue here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6541271 Do you know about the solution, I cannot open it entirely.

Comment: Do you set any connection timeouts defined on your client builder?